# Argument "Index" is not a valid value

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a tool to commit dcm files and now I have a bug that refuse to commit removed files when they had been used as a source file for other added files.

Procedure :

1- Copy file called FILE_A and name it as FILE_B and implement some changes to the parameters in FILE_B then commit changes using the tool( with choosing FILE_A as a reference file ) .. works totally fine.

2- Delete FILE_A and keep FILE_B and then use the tool to commit  .. tool will crash and be closed.

And here is the lines that throw the exception and close the tool :

```
If FilesGrid.Item(0, a).Value = True And FilesGrid.Item(2, a).Value.ToString() = "Removed" Then

    FilesRemoved.Add(FileLocalPos.Item(FilesGrid.Item(1, a).Value.ToString))
    myFileVector.Add(FileLocalPos.Item(FilesGrid.Item(1, a).Value.ToString))

End If
```

The exception message is :

`Argument "index" is not a valid value`

Your help is highly appreciated ..

Comment: By the way, you've asked 7 questions and never accepted even 1 answer. This is not the way to get people to pay attention to your questions.

Comment: FilesGrid is a datagridview that show loaded files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:

Save `FilesGrid.Item(1, a).Value.ToString` to a variable:

```
If FilesGrid.Item(0, a).Value = True And FilesGrid.Item(2, a).Value.ToString() = "Removed" Then
    Dim l_itemIndex = FilesGrid.Item(1, a).Value.ToString

    FilesRemoved.Add(FileLocalPos.Item(l_itemIndex))
    myFileVector.Add(FileLocalPos.Item(l_itemIndex))
End If
```

Comment: thank you i will try your answer and then let you know if i got a problem

Comment: @A.Wad - You are using so many indices, it's pretty much impossible to say which is throwing the error. On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: the error is occuring in this line :  FilesRemoved.Add(FileLocalPos.Item(FilesGrid.Item(1, a).Value.ToString))

Answer (score 0):

This message means the Collection does not contain the item you tried to locate using the Item function.

To prevent this message, use the Contains method before trying to reference the Item.
E.g.

```
If FilesGrid.Contains(0, a) and FilesGrid.Contains(2, 1) Then
    If FilesGrid.Item(0, a).Value = True And FilesGrid.Item(2, a).Value.ToString() = "Removed" Then
```